# unable to save the r output in hdfs

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, sparkr

I am running `sparkR` program. I want to save the output in `hdfs`.The output saves in local perfectly,but if i mention `hdfs` path means it throws error.
I am executing from shell script.this is my shell script:

```
/SparkR-pkg/lib/SparkR/sparkR-submit --master yarn-client examples/pi.R yarn-client 4
```

this is my r code.

```
library(SparkR)
getwd()
setwd('hdfs://ip-172-31-41-199.us-wes t2.compute.internal:8020/user/karun/output/')
args <- commandArgs(trailing = TRUE)
if (length(args) < 1) {
print("Usage: pi <master> [<slices>]")
q("no")
}
sc <- sparkR.init(args[[1]], "PiR")
slices <- ifelse(length(args) > 1, as.integer(args[[2]]), 2)
n <- 100000 * slices
piFunc <- function(elem) {
rands <- runif(n = 2, min = -1, max = 1)
val <- ifelse((rands[1]^2 + rands[2]^2) < 1, 1.0, 0.0)
val
}
piFuncVec <- function(elems) {
message(length(elems))
rands1 <- runif(n = length(elems), min = -1, max = 1)
rands2 <- runif(n = length(elems), min = -1, max = 1)
val <- ifelse((rands1^2 + rands2^2) < 1, 1.0, 0.0)
sum(val)
}
rdd <- parallelize(sc, 1:n, slices)
count <- reduce(lapplyPartition(rdd, piFuncVec), sum)
output <- paste("Pi is roughly", 4.0 * count / n, "\n")
output <- paste(output, "Num elements in RDD ", count(rdd), "\n")
writeLines(output, con = "file.txt", sep = "\n", useBytes = FALSE)
cat("Num elements in RDD ", count(rdd), "\n")
```

i tried many method to save the output in hdfs link sink,write.data,writetype etc.. i am trying the change the working directory by mentioning setwd().This query is also not working .it throws error

> Error in setwd("hdfs://ip-172-31-41-199.us-west- 2.compute.internal:8020/user/karun/output/") : 
>      cannot change working directory
>      Execution halted

I have been troubleshooting for 2 days .any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why are trying to change your working directory? I think it's better and easier try to save to hdfs. Do you have write acces to hdfs?

Comment: yes but whenever i mentioning the hdfs path it shows No such file or directory execution halted

Comment: how to save the output in hdfs..any other options

Comment: The package rhdfs has a function write.hdfs which you can try.